# PHP newSimpleXMLElement returns attribute value instead of node value

Tags: php, simplexml

The base `$user` object via `var_dump()`:

```
object(SimpleXMLElement)#191 (5) { 
    ["@attributes"]=> array(1) { 
        ["size"]=> string(5) "small" 
    } 
    [0]=> string(50) "userserve-ak.last.fm/serve/34/100389411.jpg" 
    [1]=> string(50) "userserve-ak.last.fm/serve/64/100389411.jpg" 
    [2]=> string(51) "userserve-ak.last.fm/serve/126/100389411.jpg" 
    [3]=> string(51) "userserve-ak.last.fm/serve/252/100389411.jpg" 
}
```

I want to get the first link: `userserve-ak.last.fm/serve/34/100389411.jpg` by using `$link->user[0];`

but instead of the link I receive:
    `object(SimpleXMLElement)#190 (1) { ["@attributes"]=> array(1) { ["size"]=> string(5) "small" } }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, it's probably a typo when you asked the question, but..

```
 $link->$user[0];
```

Should be

```
 $link->user[0];
```

And..Why not use a regular array?

You could..

```
$user = json_decode(json_encode($link->user),true);
```

Then `$user[0]` will contain your link.